# Execute an Octave function requiring an array through php using shell?

Tags: php, octave

I am trying to pass an array to the octave function. Getting the array from HTML form in PHP

```
$htmlinput=$_POST['data']
$cmd="(/opt/local/bin/octave --silent --eval "mymult($htmlinput)")";
$output= exec($cmd);
echo  $output; //My $cmd doesnt take the array $htmlinput.
```

Comment: well, first of all, you need to escape your double quotes.

Comment: if that's not your bug, please provide a proper minimal working example with data to test.